# Counting number of view of specific file on server (php)

Tags: php

Is there a way to count how many views a specific file has had on my server?

So for example I've some file on `data/` directory, `data1.pdf`, `data2.pdf`, `data3.pdf`. And the URLs are, for example, `https://www.example.com/data/data1.pdf`. How can I count the total number of view on `data1.pdf`?

In my case, the user access to resource by QR code scan. So I need to catch this action to count the total number of view by specific resources.
Moreover I need to update count value in a MySQL database, for example `data1.pdf`: 10 views, `data2.pdf`: 8 views, `data3.pdf`: 6 views.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you able to change the url in the QR-Code, or is it too late ?

Comment: You webserver log should show which files have been requested

Comment: smwhr, it’s too late I need a way without change any url.. if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to intercept the "intent" of the user before giving her the files she requested.

There are multiple ways to do that. Since you already have an interface to the link (the QR-Code), you can use it to first send the user to a first "counter page" at the url `www.example.com/serve.php?f=data/data1.pdf` (that would be the url encoded in the QR-Code)

The file would look like that :

```
<?php
  $requested_file = $_GET['f'];
  $conn = //init your connexion
  $conn->execute("UPDATE counters SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE filename = ?", requested_file);
  
  header("Location: "+$requested_file);
  exit;
```

### if you can't change the link

In that case, it will be a little more tricky because you still want to intercept the user before she reaches the file *but* she already has a direct link.

I woul suggest using a `.htaccess` file that redirect all the request in a directory to our `serve.php`. Be aware that by default this htaccess file will redirect ALL traffic in the `data` folder to our php file so you will certainly need to do some extra work to integrate it inside your domain

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /                                                              
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/data     [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /serve.php?f=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

and `serve.php` will be changed to :

```
<?php
  $requested_file = $_GET['f'];
  $conn = //init your connexion
  $conn->execute("UPDATE counters SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE filename = ?", requested_file);
  
  $content = file_get_contents($server_path_to_requested_file);
  header("Content-type: application/pdf"); //change that if you handle multiple files
  echo $content;
  exit;
```

Drawback here again is that you need PHP to read and spit out the content of the file (that will be slower than directly serving the file)

Comment: In my case I already have the link to the qr code and I can’t change it. So this solution is possibile if I can change the link.

Comment: Updated to reflect your new requirements !